# Can’t open mailbox {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX:

Tags: php, gmail

I'd like to open Gmail mailbox. But the following error was occurred.

> Notice: Unknown: Can't open mailbox
>   {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX: invalid remote
>   specification (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0

Below is my code.

```
$mailserver = "{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX";
$username = "XXXXXX@gmail.com";
$password = "YYYYYY";
$mailbox = @imap_open($mailserver, $username, $password);
var_dump($mailbox);exit;  // false
```

So could you tell me the solution?

Comment: Why don't you want to validate the certificate? Certainly googles email service _does_ offer a valid certificate?

Comment: Besides that: the code works without problem for me. Could this be an issue with your php version? What version do you use?

Comment: I don't need to validate the certificate. So I deleted the **novalidate-cert**. But it occurred the following error. `Notice: Unknown: Can't open mailbox {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX: invalid remote specification (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: Sounds like you got that flag wrong: that additional flag _suppresses_ the validation. So without the flag you _do_ validate the certificate. Which certainly does make sense.

Comment: My PHP version is 5.6.7. And I use MAMP.

Comment: The version sounds fine so far. But indeed I heard a lot of strange issues with mac environments. No further idea, sorry. As said: the code is perfectly fine and works (for me and others too).